# Google authentication using different CLIENT ID's

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-authentication

I want to use Google Authentication Oauth 2 to validate users to access many domains using the code provided by Google in a library on my server. I downloaded and installed the code supplied by Google and everything works fine until I change the Client Id and Client Secret to use a different project that I set up in the Developers Console.

Essentially what I am trying to do is use the Google_Client.php and its dependent code as a shared code base to authenticate over many different projects but it looks like the config.php file always takes precedence even if I set the Client id and Secret for each project on each of my scripts.

This is how part of the config.php file looks like:

```
global $apiConfig;
$apiConfig = array(
  'use_objects' => false,
  'application_name' => 'My Name',
  'oauth2_client_id' => 'MY CLIENT ID HERE',
  'oauth2_client_secret' => 'MY SECRET HERE',
  'oauth2_redirect_uri' => 'MY REDIRECT HERE'
);
```

In the Google_Client.php file these functions exists

```
public function setClientId($clientId) {
  global $apiConfig;
  $apiConfig['oauth2_client_id'] = $clientId;
  self::$auth->clientId = $clientId;
}

public function setClientSecret($clientSecret) {
  global $apiConfig;
  $apiConfig['oauth2_client_secret'] = $clientSecret;
  self::$auth->clientSecret = $clientSecret;
}
```

I call these functions from my script under each domain passing a different Client Id and Secret like this:

```
require_once 'PATH_TO_LIBRARY/Google_Client.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("MY NAME");
$client->setClientId('MY CLIENT ID');
$client->setClientSecret('MY SECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('MY REDIRECT');
```

Everything works fine if the CLIENT ID and SECRET is the same in my script as in the config.php file. One solution would be to comment out the global $apiConfig; line in setClientId and setClientSecret functions in the Google_Client.php file but this is not very elegant. I really do not want to have copies of Google_Client.php and the rest of the code that comes with it for each domain that I have running on my server rather share the code between all domains where I want to use Google authentication.

Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Cheers

Comment: why do you say that "it looks like the config.php file always takes precedence"? I haven't worked with this version of the library, but looking at the code it seems that you can just leave the config.php with empty values and set the values with the set* functions, which overwrite the $apiConfig. What error do you get when you do this? PS: there's a new version of the library at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: @DalmTo, when I say it does not work means when I use a different Client_ID and Client secret parameters it still uses the parameters set up in the config.php file and not the ones I define in my code.